# How to separate amino acid, number and amino acid string?

Tags: search, python-2.7, csv

Right now, I have amino acid string.
The amino acid mutation column looks like this A59M, T133G, K2*, G1927? and ? only.
So, I tried to use re to separate one column into three columns and remove those ? only but keep G1297?.

```
import re 
AA_mut = AA_mut.replace('p.','')
m = re.search(r'^(\w+)(\d+)(\S+)$',AA_mut)
```

But, I got
(A5,9,M; T13,3,M;....)

Please give me some advise. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\w` matches letters and digits in perl.  It looks to me like it's doing the same thing in python.

You might try being more explicit.  Is that a single, capital letter on the front?  If so maybe you want something like

```
^([A-Z])(\d+)(\D+)$
```

In perl:

```
print join ("<>", m/^([A-Z])(\d+)(\D+)$/) while <DATA>;

__DATA__
A59M
T133G
K2*
G1927?
?
```

prints

```
A<>59<>M
T<>133<>G
K<>2<>*
G<>1927<>?
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have:

```
data = ["A59M", "T133G", "K2*", "G1927?", "?"]
```

You can extract it using:

```
out = [(s[0], s[1:-1], s[-1]) for s in data if len(s) > 2]
```

This gives me:

```
out == [('A', '59', 'M'), ('T', '133', 'G'), 
        ('K', '2', '*'), ('G', '1927', '?')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re 
AA_mut = AA_mut.replace('p.','')
m = re.search(r'^(\w)(\d+)(\S+)$',AA_mut)
```

I use this one to solve my problem. The original \w+ leaves one digit for \d+ and one alphabet for \S+. Once I removed the "+". It takes only first alphabet and leaves other parts.